# How can I solve this below MySQL database code please

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Consider the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT
  e.id,
  e.edu_name, 
  IF(COUNT(rw.id) > 0, COUNT(rw.id), 0) AS row_Number,
  IF(COUNT(s.id) > 0, COUNT(s.id), 0) AS stu_Number,
  IF(COUNT(rm.id) > 0, COUNT(rm.id), 0) AS room_Number
FROM `education` e
LEFT JOIN `my_rows` rw ON e.id = rw.edu_id
LEFT JOIN `my_rooms` rm ON e.id = rm.edu_id
GROUP BY e.id
```

I have three tables in my database that are in the following relation to each other:

1. `education` — `id`, `edu_name`.
2. `my_rows` — `id`, `edu_id`, `row_name`.
3. `my_rooms` — `id`, `edu_id`, `row_id`, `room_name`.

I am trying to determine
how many rows and rooms there exist in each education entry in the above schema.
However, the result I’m getting with the above query is incorrect.

For example, if I have 3 rows and 5 rooms,
it incorrectly gives me 15 rows and 15 rooms, instead.

I want to obtain the number of rows and rooms separately for each education entry.

Comment: What is the alias `s` used in `s.id` in your code?

Comment: I think you might want inner join rather than left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count return the number of not null value  .. if you have a join between 5 x 3 rows  you get 15 rows as result and count return 15 .. but for avoid this you could use the  count(distinct col)

```
SELECT e.id, e.edu_name, 
IF(COUNT(distinct rw.id) > 0, COUNT(distinct rw.id), 0) AS row_Number,
IF(COUNT(distinct s.id) > 0, COUNT(distinct s.id), 0) AS stu_Number,
IF(COUNT(distinct rm.id) > 0, COUNT(distinct rm.id), 0) AS room_Number
FROM `education` e
LEFT JOIN `my_rows` rw ON e.id = rw.edu_id
LEFT JOIN `my_rooms` rm ON e.id = rm.edu_id
GROUP BY e.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You are joining along different dimensions, so you are multiplying rows.  I have no idea why you have `if()` conditions, given that `count()` does not return `NULL` values.

The "quick-and-dirty" solution is:

```
SELECT e.id, e.edu_name, 
       COUNT(distinct rw.id) AS row_Number,
       COUNT(distinct s.id) AS stu_Number,
       COUNT(distinct rm.id) AS room_Number
FROM `education` e LEFT JOIN
     `my_rows` rw
      ON e.id = rw.edu_id LEFT JOIN
      `my_rooms` rm ON e.id = rm.edu_id
GROUP BY e.id;
```

This assumes that you have fixed the query so `s` is defined.

Assuming that `e.id` is the primary key of the first table, then you can eliminate the outer aggregation.  This is usually a win in terms of performance.  The resulting query would look something like:

```
SELECT e.id, e.edu_name, 
       (SELECT COUNT(rw.id) FROM `my_rows` rw WHERE e.id = rw.edu_id ) AS row_Number,
       (SELET COUNT(distinct rm.id FROM `my_rooms` rm WHERE e.id = rm.edu_id) AS room_Number
FROM `education` e;
```